# How to find the preference key for a certain setting in the Preferences dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I need to set the value RSE UI to unchecked by default.

I just need to access this value programmatically but I cannot find it.

The value is located under Window > Preferences > General > Startup and shutdown.

Comment: Sorry but what is 'RSE UI'? I don't see anything like that on that preference page.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

A simple brute force solution:

1. create a full, deep copy of all your workspace settings files
2. start Eclipse; and that property you are interested in manually and exit eclipse
3. compare the new settings files with those in your copy

That should ideally tell you which settings file contains that property, and how it is named "programmatically".

With that knowledge, you can use any kind of text replacement tool (like sed) to simply update that settings file automatically later on.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Eclipse plug-in called *Preferences Spy*.

http://blog.vogella.com/2014/12/28/preferences-spy-for-eclipse-ide-and-rcp/

It adds a view that allows you to log all or certain preference changes. For each change, the affected preference node, the preference name, and the old and new value is shown.

At least for me, it helped to find the preference keys for certain settings.