# How to improve RCP application start times

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

Migrating our RCP application from Eclipse 3.7 to e4 resulted in significant startup time degradation.
It went from 3 seconds on Eclipse 3.7 up to 17 seconds on latest 4.6.1 target platform.

Two visible bottle necks are the activation of `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme` and `org.eclipse.help` bundles.

I was wondering if there is anything we can do to improve this?
I don't use any themes and don't need any support for the help system.

During the startup my application hangs for about 10 seconds doing this:

```
Finding activator for org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.10.100.v20160523-0836 [832]
Finding activator for org.eclipse.help_3.7.0.v20160602-1307 [915]
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to remove them from dependencies.
But is there any way to at least lazy load, postpone, fake, ignore, etc.. their activation?

Comment: There is an _Enable theming_ option in the _General > Appearance_ preferences. The preference can certainly be changed programmatically and may help to reduce the startup time. The option is available since Eclipse 4.6.

Comment: Regarding the help system: there is an article describing how to **add** the help system (https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-AddingHelpToRCP/index.html), hence I think there should be a way to remove/not add it. What did you do to remove the help system?

Comment: @Rüdiger, do you know what is the preference which disables the theming in RCP applications? I see it does have some effect in Eclipse Neon, it gets more responsive. I want to completely avoid this thingy in my RCP application.

Comment: Regarding the Help, The link is outdated. In the past it was possible to remove Help dependencies, or add if needed. Now as far as I can tell the entire org.eclipse.ui depends on org.eclipse.help. Strange improvement. But I would survive if at least I could bypass its activation. It is a killer package which has completely no use for my cause.

Comment: Strange improvement, indeed. That makes me think of another hack: what if you create a drop-in replacement of `org.eclipse.help.ui` that provides the same API but implements no-ops?

Comment: I don't know the name of the theming preference. However, you should be able to find out yourself with the help of this tool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845433/how-to-find-the-preference-key-for-a-certain-setting-in-the-preferences-dialog/40846546#40846546